How to prevent jagged cloth, and keep material back
I have two questions for this simulation:

As shown above, the cloth material is moving through the hand. I think it would work better and look better if I could somehow keep the cloth material back a bit, as it's currently like a half cape.

Also, as shown above here, the cloth looks very jagged. Is there a good way to fix this? It's for a challenge, so I can't edit the animation, but I can edit the cloth around it. Thanks!

Add more geo with a SubSurf mod, either before or after the simulation is run. Before will make running the simulation slower but will give more detail in the final output, adding the mod after is basically the opposite.
